# Repo sync error on macOS with _ssl.so image not found

Tags: python, macos, android-source

I've got my AOSP repo initialized after downloading a tar file from [mirro.tuna](https://mirror.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/AOSP/), but I met the following error when I executed `repo sync`.

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Android/Source/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    from git_config import init_ssh, close_ssh
  File "/Volumes/Android/Source/aosp/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 24, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log, the error occurs when `import ssl` is executed. I found libssl.1.0.0.dylib is missing. It could be due to my partial update on `brew install python@2` or some other unknown broken. I reinstalled the `python@2` through Homebrew and the error disappears.

```
brew reinstall python@2
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy's solution fixed my problem on Python 3 as well. Cannot comment directly so put a separate answer here. Just run

`brew reinstall python@3`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what `python` symlink to version, so it is better to reinstall `python`

```
brew reinstall python
```